# Is there an rx framework for bluetooth classic?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, rx-swift

I set up my project to use `rx-bluetooth-kit` to `scan` for `peripherals`. In my `subscription` I received alot of `peripherals` but for some obscure reason, I coudn't find the actual `peripheral` that I wanted to connect to. Then it hit me that the `peripheral` I'm interested in don't use `BLE` but `bluetooth-classic`. Perhaps this could be the reason it's not shown?

So I guess my first question is: Can `rx-bluetooth-kit` `scan` and connect to `BLE` only? Or should I also be able to find `bluetooth-classic` `peripherals`?

Second question: If it can only `scan` for `BLE`, is there another `rx` framework that works with `bluetooth-classic` or am I stuck with using `core-bluetooth` (or some variant of it; not sure what you use in terms of apple frameworks when working with `bluetooth-classic`).

Comment: Core Bluetooth only works with BLE.  Apps on iOS cannot generally work with classic Bluetooth peripherals. The external connectivity framework can be used with classic Bluetooth peripherals that include Apple's mfi chipset and this requires the app to be authorised or produced by the mfi licensee. Audio Bluetooth peripherals (headsets, speakers) can be accessed using the av framework but just as audio routes, there is no app-accessible discovery or pairing capabilities

Comment: So are you saying that if the device I'm trying to connect to isn't an MFi device (which it's not), then there is no way for an iPhone to connect to that device!!!

Comment: Well, there is no way for an app you write to connect to that device, no.  IOS supports [some profiles](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204387) natively, but if your peripheral uses a profile that isn't on the list, like SPP, there is no way to connect to it